# How to authorize an API endpoint with both JWT and Azure Ad token?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, api, authorization

I have created a react application which is calling a .net API as backend service. In my react app there are two ways to login, first is using username and password and second one is by using azure ad login.

When we login using username and password it hits the api endpoint and generates a token and authorize the user on the basis of token generated. In the same way I want to authorize a user when he logins from azure ad part.

So how can I authorize the back-end API endpoint when user login with either username or password or with the help of azure ad login.

Startup.cs(this is my code for how I handled the jwt authorization flow)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8082").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BaseWebApi", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Jwt Authorization",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                         new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id= "Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[]{}
                    }
                });

});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:key"]))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DemoJWTToken v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("corsapp");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "ClaimsPrinciple" object, can be found by using the keyword "User" on a controller on an API.

This will allow you to build a logic that depends on if a token is present or not, or on a set of usernames, or whatever you want to do really.

Comment: Hi Morten Bork, Is there any sample or reference link for the same which you are taking about?

Comment: https://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-7.0